# creating subsites within my drupal site

Tags: views, subsites

I'm trying to create a subsite within our current drupal site. The v1 pass is all static HTML, but very soon, like as soon as I get v1 up I'm going to have to add in a few blocks for dynamic content.

I was wondering what the best way to structure this would be. We currently have a "chromeless-html-page" content type which i'm working with. But I wasn't sure if was the most efficient way as I would have to create a chromeless-page object for each page and then link them together. I was wondering would it make more sense to create a subsite-content-type that would be a view and then display all of those subsite-pages?

not sure if that makes sense or if i'm even on the right track with my question. I'm truly lost any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subsites are spread across multiple sub/domains, you can use [domain](http://drupal.org/project/domain) to display a different set of nodes per-domain.